# Segmentation Fault while acessing shared memory

Tags: linux, ipc, shared-memory

I want to use shared memory for my application.
I have two processes. One will be creating shared memory (writer) and one will attach to this share memory to read it(reader).
From writer side i am able to write in shared memory. But from reader code i am able to get and attach to memory successfully.
But when i try to read from this memory it generates seg fault.

Writer code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

#include<sys/ipc.h>
#include<sys/shm.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<errno.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<string.h>

#define BUF_SIZE 4096
#define SHM_KEY 0x1239
#define MAX_FIFO_ELEMENTS   100


struct stcomndstruct
{
    unsigned char status;
    unsigned int command_id;
    unsigned int event_id;
    unsigned int event_subid;
    unsigned int datasize;
    unsigned int offset;
};

struct stcirFIFO
{
     int head;
     int tail;
    //unsigned int status;
    struct stcomndstruct command[MAX_FIFO_ELEMENTS];
};



int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   int shmid, numtimes,i=0;
   struct stcirFIFO *shmp;
   char *bufptr;
   int spaceavailable;
   shmid = shmget(SHM_KEY, sizeof(struct stcirFIFO), 0644|IPC_CREAT);
   if (shmid == -1) {
      perror("Shared memory");
      return 1;
   }

   // Attach to the segment to get a pointer to it.
   shmp = shmat(shmid, NULL, 0);
   if (shmp == (void *) -1) {
      perror("Shared memory attach");
      return 1;
   }
   printf("\n WRITER ADDRESS %d",shmp);
   /* Transfer blocks of data from buffer to shared memory */
   shmp->head=0;
   for(i=0;i<60;i++)
   {
       shmp->head=shmp->head+1;
       sleep(1);
   }
   spaceavailable = BUF_SIZE;

   printf("Writing Process: Wrote %d times\n", numtimes);

sleep(10);
   if (shmdt(shmp) == -1) {
      perror("shmdt");
      return 1;
   }

   if (shmctl(shmid, IPC_RMID, 0) == -1) {
      perror("shmctl");
      return 1;
   }
   printf("Writing Process: Complete\n");
   return 0;
}
```

reader code snap:

```
#define KEY_FIFO_VAR_SH_MEM 0x1239
void reader()
{
int shmid,i;
    struct stcirFIFO *shmp;
    printf("\n\n*******shared mem init called\n");
    shmid = shmget(KEY_FIFO_VAR_SH_MEM, sizeof(struct stcirFIFO), 0644|IPC_CREAT);
    if (shmid == -1) {
        perror("Shared memory");
        return 1;
    }else
    {
        printf("\nLocate sucessfull...");
    }

    // Attach to the segment to get a pointer to it.
    shmp = shmat(shmid, NULL, 0);
    if (shmp == (void *) -1) {
        perror("Shared memory attach");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }else
    {


        printf("\nAttach sucessfull...address %d",shmp);
        printf("address of head %d",&(shmp->head));

    }
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        printf("Read Value %d",*shmp);
        sleep(1);
    }
}
```

Strace Log:

```
write(1, "\n\n*******shared mem init called", 31

*******shared mem init called) = 31
write(1, "\n", 1
)                       = 1
shmget(0x1239, 2408, IPC_CREAT|0644)    = 13762590
write(1, "\nLocate sucessfull...", 21
Locate sucessfull...)  = 21
shmat(13762590, NULL, 0)                = 0x7f4c22a71000
write(1, "\nAttach sucessfull...address 581"..., 38
Attach sucessfull...address 581373952) = 38
write(1, "address of head 581373952", 25address of head 581373952) = 25
--- SIGSEGV {si_signo=SIGSEGV, si_code=SEGV_MAPERR, si_addr=0x22a71000} ---
+++ killed by SIGSEGV (core dumped) +++
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: Don't just post code snippets, post minimal, but complete code that can be compiled and still reproduces the error. Your currently posted reader code does not produce SIGSEGV.

Comment: Actually code is too big about 50 files so , therefore i am posting only part which is causing seg fault. From Strace post you can see its causing seg fault.

Comment: You need to trim those 50 files to minimal but complete example. It took 30 seconds for me to add relevant parts to your reader code to make it compile and make sure, it does not crash in that way. You should do this also and find out, what actually is causing this segfault, not post the code without context, that you think causes segfault, but doesn't.

Comment: For example. you may have a code, where `printf("Hello world\n");` causes segfault, but it is pointless to post only this line and ask for help, because the problem obviously relies somewhere else. And it is also pointless to make assumptions about the relevant code to include as you actually don't know, what the actual problem is. That's why we need minimal but complete example.

Comment: using gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10)  causes seg fault but when i compile same code with gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.9-2014.09_linux toolchain for petalinux it work perfectly fine on another development board i have..

Answer (score 0):

A segmentation fault occurs when you're accessing un-authorized memory.
shmget() returns the identifier of the System V shared memory segment associated with the value of the argument key.  It may be used either to obtain the identifier of a previously created shared memory segment (when shmflg is zero and key does not have the value IPC_PRIVATE), or to create a new set.

So on receiver side you should use the same key in shmget();
shmid = shmget(**KEY_FIFO_VAR_SH_MEM**, sizeof(struct stcirFIFO), 0644|IPC_CREAT);

Comment: Dear sir, I have updated code just name is different but key value is same.

Answer (score 0):

```
    struct stcirFIFO *shmp;

    ...

    printf("Read Value %d",*shmp);
```

Since `shmp` is of type `struct stcrFIFO *`, you're trying to pass a `struct stcrFIFO` to `printf` with the `%d` format specifier. It's expecting an `int`.